# Display Selected Message String

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm working on a method that goes through all of my array messages and displays the selected message. I'm new to Java so I'm still trying to figure out methods and Arrays. When I run this, it says that it's successful but it doesn't display anything. Can someone help me figure this out.

```
package chatbox;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChatBox
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 String chatMessages[] = new String[10];
 //declare arrays
 chatMessages[0]= "Pepperoni";
 chatMessages[1]= "Olives";
 chatMessages[2]= "Cheese";
 chatMessages[3]= "Onions";
 chatMessages[4]= "Bacon";
 chatMessages[5]= "Tomato sauce";
 chatMessages[6]= "Bell peppers";
 chatMessages[7]= "Mushrooms";
 chatMessages[8]= "Sausage";
 chatMessages[9]= "Beef";       

 } 

 Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

public Scanner chatCannedMessage(String chatMessages)
          {              
for (int i=0;i<chatMessages.length;i++){ 

     System.out.println(chatMessages[i]); //Prints Message
 }

System.out.println("Select a message");

String chatMessage = scan.next();

scan.nextLine();      

 return scan;

          }
}
```

Comment: Are you working with IDE (like Eclipse)? If not, please post command line commands you are using to compile and run your code.

Comment: You apparently created `shoutOutCannedMessage()` method to print your messages but you **never** invoke it. So your `main()` method assigns string values to your array and quits.

Comment: @PM 77-1 Thanks for the reply. I will read some more about methods. I didn't know there was more I had to do to invoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PM 77-1 said, you never invoked your `shoutOutCannedMessage` method and also never print out or return any string.
I tried to minimize changes to your code, and I think this might be what you intended to do.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShoutBox {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String messages[] = new String[10];
        //declare 10 arrays
        messages[0] = "Pepperoni";
        messages[1] = "Olives";
        messages[2] = "Cheese";
        messages[3] = "Onions";
        messages[4] = "Bacon";
        messages[5] = "Tomato sauce";
        messages[6] = "Bell peppers";
        messages[7] = "Mushrooms";
        messages[8] = "Sausage";
        messages[9] = "Beef";

        String m = new ShoutBox().shoutOutCannedMessage(messages);
        System.out.println(m);
    }

    public String shoutOutCannedMessage(String[] messages) {
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(i+". "+messages[i]); //Should print the messages
        }

        System.out.println("Select a message");

        int idx = scan.nextInt();

        String message = messages[idx];

        return message;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. So    String m = new     ShoutBox().shoutOutCannedMessage(messages);
        System.out.println(m); is what invokes the method?

Comment: `new ShoutBox().shoutOutCannedMessage(messages);` invokes the method, and `System.out.println(m);` prints out the string returned by the method.